# Illegal base64 data at input byte for seemingly valid png

Tags: go, base64, png

I'm attempting to decode a data URL that was generated from a javascript canvas' toDataURL function.

The following golang application fails with the error `illegal base64 data at input byte 129)`

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    pngData := "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAF0AAAABCAYAAAC8PaJPAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAALVJREFUGFdt0MsKQVEYhuG9CeU0VgamihBl6hqMXYoLchduQFuKicyFARPn0/J+9Q2tevrba639H1YcQhhHUTTBACloFZHFw3FJbODj7xdxjSqmqGCHms+3vv8m3nDwWSA+vVcipjFHHlcMcUTBtcuueSHqfgzlVJ7Nn/o99s5Qf3v0sUAHK///JbahmZQ3gy4S96OZc9A90fkdepM6tNTHDOqz6T3NofeTluuqV82oHOrphNEPw3UwfBVmbU4AAAAASUVORK5CYII="
    pngData, err := url.PathUnescape(pngData)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to unescape", err.Error())
        return
    }
    pngData = strings.Replace(pngData, "+", "", -1)
    _, err = base64.URLEncoding.WithPadding(base64.NoPadding).DecodeString(pngData)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to decode", err.Error())
    }
}
```

If I pass the value from pngData into a [web-based base64 to png converter](https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter), it has no problem generating the image. (a horizontal line of white-ish values)

[image: proof of valid base64]

I have tried StdEncoding, RawURLEncoding, and their Raw counterparts. I've also tried with or without padding and I've tried the same pngData string with an additional = and without the trailing =.

Any thoughts on why Golang is refusing to decode this data?

Some of the images I get from the canvas decode just fine. But some, like this one, do not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Steven Penny's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65136965/1256452) shows a way to do this, but I have to ask:

- Why do you call `url.PathUnescape`?  The data contain no path escape characters (no `%`-encoding).  The call is harmless but unnecessary.
- Why did you use the alternate encoding (`URLEncoding`)?  As we see in the [base64 package documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/base64/), the difference between the standard encoding and the alternate encoding is that the alternate encoding uses `-` and `_` in place of `+` and `/`.  But if we look at the data string, it contains plus signs and slashes, and has no dashes or underscores, so it has clearly been encoded with the standard encoding.
- Why did you call for `base64.NoPadding`?  The input data ends with `=`, which is a padding character.
- Why did you call for `base64.NoPadding` *via* `base64.URLEncoding.WithPadding(base64.NoPadding)`?  The documentation shows us that this can be spelled `base64.RawURLEncoding`.
- Why did you explicitly ask to strip out `+` characters (not a good idea) but not `/` characters?

If we drop all of those (and split up a long input line for posting purposes) we get this ([playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/RDwSkGV1xBe)):

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    data := "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAF0AAAABCAYAAAC8PaJPAAAABH" +
        "NCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAALVJREFUGFdt0MsKQVEYhuG9CeU0Vgam" +
        "ihBl6hqMXYoLchduQFuKicyFARPn0/J+9Q2tevrba639H1YcQh" +
        "hHUTTBACloFZHFw3FJbODj7xdxjSqmqGCHms+3vv8m3nDwWSA+" +
        "vVcipjFHHlcMcUTBtcuueSHqfgzlVJ7Nn/o99s5Qf3v0sUAHK/" +
        "//JbahmZQ3gy4S96OZc9A90fkdepM6tNTHDOqz6T3NofeTluuq" +
        "V82oHOrphNEPw3UwfBVmbU4AAAAASUVORK5CYII="
    b, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(data)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to decode: %s\n", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("bytes begin with: %q\n", b[0:4])
    }
}
```

Comment: Honestly, the answer to the majority of your questions was "because nothing else was working".  I should have edited my answer to only include the relevant details.

Comment: And now that I've pared it down, I've learned that all of my attempted fixes simply concealed the true problem.

I was passing the base64 data into my request via the URL, and go's http servemux was stripping out the triple slash (///) leading to invalid data.

I have since changed to (double) URL-encoding the data before I provide it to my handler.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work fine:

```
package main

import (
   "encoding/base64"
   "image"
   "image/png"
   "os"
   "strings"
)

func main() {
   s := `iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAF0AAAABCAYAAAC8PaJPAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAALVJ
REFUGFdt0MsKQVEYhuG9CeU0VgamihBl6hqMXYoLchduQFuKicyFARPn0/J+9Q2tevrba639H1YcQhhHU
TTBACloFZHFw3FJbODj7xdxjSqmqGCHms+3vv8m3nDwWSA+vVcipjFHHlcMcUTBtcuueSHqfgzlVJ7Nn/
o99s5Qf3v0sUAHK///JbahmZQ3gy4S96OZc9A90fkdepM6tNTHDOqz6T3NofeTluuqV82oHOrphNEPw3U
wfBVmbU4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=`
   d := base64.NewDecoder(base64.StdEncoding, strings.NewReader(s))
   p, e := png.Decode(d)
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   c, e := os.Create("a.png")
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   png.Encode(c, p.(*image.NRGBA))
}
```